# ExpressJS application to get Instagram media works on locahost and not on Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, instagram

I will explain the problems in more detail.

I'm trying to do a really simple little practice. Through a link, the ID of an Instagram post is passed as a parameter.
After this, '? __ a = 1' is added to the URL for subsequent data processing once the JSON object has been obtained.

On localhost this works fine and I get the JSON object. But once deployed as a function in Firebase, although it accepts the request without errors, it does not return a JSON object. Instead it returns HTML content, like this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\" class=\"no-js not-logged-in client-root\">\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n        <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n\n        <title>\nLogin • Instagram\n</title>\n\n
```

....

**Does anyone know what is causing this problem?**

...

*Localhost:*

[image: Localhost]

*Deployed like a Firebase Function:*
[image: Deployed like a Firebase Function]

I briefly attach the code of my application.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const server = require("./src/server");

const d = functions
    .runWith({
            memory: "2GB",
            timeoutSeconds: 120
    })
    .https
    .onRequest(server);

module.exports = {d};
```

**server/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();


app
    .use(cors({origin: true}))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
    .use("/", require("./route"))

    .get('*', (_, res) =>
        res.status(404)
        .json({success: false, data: "Endpoint not found"}));


module.exports = app;
```

**server/route.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const controller = require("./controller");

router.get("/:url", controller.getImageVideo);

module.exports = router;
```

**server/controller.js**

```
'use strict'

const axios = require('axios');

    
async function getImageVideo(req, res) {
    const URL_id = req.params.url;
    const URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + URL_id + '?__a=1';

    const metadata = await axios.get(URL);
    const test = metadata.data;

    return res
        .json({
            test
        });

}



module.exports = {
    getAllLanguages,
    getImageVideo
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find the answer? I'm facing the same issue!